# Can't run 'heroku bash' command in cmd

Tags: laravel, heroku, heroku-cli

I am making a PHP:Laravel application and I run `heroku bash` command yesterday and it worked fine. However today i tried running the same command (`heroku bash`) in cdm and it throws me this error:

> ECONNRESET: read ECONNRESET

I've tried updating heroku but it doesn't work.

*********Edit (June 15th)

I'm able to use the Heroku Web Console and use `heroku bash` from there.
Still can't use `heroku bash` from cmd, same error.

Comment: Check your logs, Heroku will explicitly provide an error code. You can then look up the issue here: [on the heroku error documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes)

Comment: I did that. It says: R13 `A dyno started with heroku run failed to attach to the invoking client.` I doesn't say how to fix it.